# FFmpeg how to extract time fragments of exact duration at set intervals?

Tags: ffmpeg

I have a video file, I know how to extract segments with ffmpeg and setting the keyframes to do so exact.

However, I would like to extract a segment of a certain duration, say 1 minute, then wait 50 seconds, again segment 1 minute, wait 50 seconds, again segment 1 minute, etc. until the end of the video file.

How can I accomplish this?
Is it possible to use a list.txt as cut input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's call your segment duration `X` and interval between end of one segment and start of another `Y`. Both in seconds. Use

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vf select='lt(mod(t,X+Y),X)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -force_key_frames expr:gte(t,n_forced*X) -f segment -segment_time X out%d.ts
```

You may want to add `-reset_timestamps 1` for zero-start timestamps for each segment. Audio is ignored and will be out of sync if present. Add a corresponding audio filter with `aselect/asetpts` to cut audio in sync.