# Extract 5 seconds of a mp4 video for every 60 seconds of the video

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to write a batch script with ffmpeg that takes every mp4 files in a folder, extracts 5 seconds out of them at 2 seconds after the start of the video, and then, if the original video lasts longer than 60 seconds, as well as that first segment, it takes another 5 seconds segment for every 60 seconds until it cannot because there are not enough seconds to segment.

Is it clear ?

I've tried this code

```
@echo off

rem Set input and output directories
set "input_dir=C:\Users\Lex\Desktop\vtrip"
set "output_dir=C:\Users\Lex\Desktop\vtrip\output"

rem Loop through all MP4 files in the input directory
for %%I in ("%input_dir%\*.mp4") do (
    rem Extract 5 seconds starting 2 seconds after the start of the video
    ffmpeg -i "%%I" -ss 2 -t 5 "%output_dir%\temp_segment_1_%%~nI.mp4"

    rem Get total duration of the video
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 "%%I"') do set "duration=%%a"

    rem Check if the duration exceeds 60 seconds
    if !duration! GTR 60 (
        rem Calculate the number of segments
        set /a "num_segments=!duration!/62"
        
        rem Extract 5-second segments every 62 seconds
        set /a "start_time=64"  REM Start from 2 seconds after the first segment
        for /l %%x in (2,1,!num_segments!) do (
            ffmpeg -i "%%I" -ss !start_time! -t 5 "%output_dir%\temp_segment_%%x_%%~nI.mp4"
            set /a "start_time+=62"
        )
    )
)
```

I've tried it on 3 files, the 2 that are under 1 minute are fine but there is one that lasts 2m29 and it only extracts 1 segment for that last one whereas it should extract 3 5-seconds segments for this one video.

Any way to fix that ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/42938574/